# Append JQuery as a separate module for Webpack

Tags: jquery, webpack, google-chrome-extension

If that matters I am working on a chrome extension(maybe it has some limitations or individual aspects, I don't know). At the start, I used jquery only in content.js specified it in manifest.json. But now I want to use it in popup.js too. Specified jquery in "content_scripts" does not provide it for popup.
What should I do for append JQuery as a separate module for Webpack bundle?

I found this:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin(
{
     $               : "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
     jQuery          : "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
     "window.jQuery" : "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
}),
```

and it works, but it inserts jquery into each file which uses it. And js files start to be so "fat". Webpack says:

```
WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
```

This can impact web performance.

Here is my full `webpack.config.js`:

```
'use strict';

const dev                               = 'development';
const prod                              = 'production';
const NODE_ENV                          = process.env.NODE_ENV ||  prod;

const baseManifest                      = require('./Source/manifest.json');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin                 = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin                    = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const webpack                           = require('webpack');
const JavaScriptObfuscator              = require('webpack-obfuscator');
const CopyPlugin                        = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackExtensionManifestPlugin    = require('webpack-extension-manifest-plugin');

module.exports =
{
    mode:  prod,

    watch: NODE_ENV ===  dev,
    watchOptions:
    {
        aggregateTimeout: 100
    },

    devtool: NODE_ENV ===  dev ? 'eval' : false,
    context: __dirname + '/Source',

    entry:
        {
            content     : './js/content.js',
            background  : './js/background.js',
            popup       : './js/popup.js'
        },

    output:
        {
            path        : __dirname + '/build',
            filename    : 'js/[name].js'
        },

    optimization:
    {
        splitChunks:
        {
            automaticNameDelimiter      : '~',
            chunks                      : 'async',
            minChunks                   : 2,
            maxAsyncRequests            : 6,
            maxInitialRequests          : 4,
            minSize                     : 30000,
            maxSize                     : 0,
            name                        : true,
            cacheGroups:
            {
                default:
                {
                    priority            : -10,
                    reuseExistingChunk  : true
                }
            }
        },

        minimize: true,
        minimizer:
        [
            new UglifyJsPlugin(
                {
                    parallel: true,
                    uglifyOptions:
                    {
                        output:
                        {
                            comments: false
                        }
                    }
                })
        ]
    },

    plugins:
        [
            new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),

            new webpack.DefinePlugin(
                {
                    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV)
                }),

            new webpack.ProvidePlugin(
                {
                    $               : "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                    jQuery          : "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                    "window.jQuery" : "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                }),

            new CopyPlugin(
                [
                    {
                        from    : './public/js',
                        to      : 'public/js'
                    },
                    {
                        from    : './_locales',
                        to      : '_locales'
                    }
                ]),

            new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
            {
                filename: 'popup.html',
                template: './popup.html',
                chunks: ['popup']
            }),

            new WebpackExtensionManifestPlugin(
                {
                    config: { base: baseManifest }
                }),

            new JavaScriptObfuscator(
                {
                    compact                         : true,

                    controlFlowFlattening           : true,
                    controlFlowFlatteningThreshold  : 0.75,

                    deadCodeInjection               : true,
                    deadCodeInjectionThreshold      : 0.5,

                    debugProtection                 : true,
                    debugProtectionInterval         : true,
                    disableConsoleOutput            : true,

                    identifierNamesGenerator        : 'hexadecimal',

                    log                             : false,

                    renameGlobals                   : false,

                    rotateStringArray               : true,
                    seed                            : new Date().getMilliseconds(),

                    selfDefending                   : false,

                    shuffleStringArray              : true,

                    stringArray                     : true,
                    stringArrayEncoding             : 'base64',
                    stringArrayThreshold            : 0.8,

                    target                          : 'browser-no-eval',
                    transformObjectKeys             : true,

                    unicodeEscapeSequence           : false
                },
                ['jquery.min.js', 'buy.js'])
        ],

    module:
        {
            rules:
            [
                {
                    test: /\.m?js$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                    use: 
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options:
                        {
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime']
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/, 
                    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
                },
                { 
                    test: /\.css$/, 
                    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'] 
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|ttf|oet|woff|woff2)$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options:
                    {
                        name: '[path][name].[ext]'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
};
```

Comment: Add as [external](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)

Comment: @GrzegorzT. The documentation says that I should add <script> to html. But if I do it everything will break. I have not ideas why html crashes when I add script to it, but it is my reality. I think I do something else wrong((

Comment: If you add `<script>` then that's enough - `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery', 'window.jQuery': 'jquery'})` This is my [example](https://github.com/tomik23/webpack-babel-corejs/blob/jquery/webpack.config.js) for jquery.

Comment: @GrzegorzT. Then I add script to popup.html it crash and popup.js don't  work.

Comment: Share the code on github, I'll look at what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could `npm install jquery` and then add the distribution to your extension through webpack.

```
const plugins = [
  new CopyWebpackPlugin(
    [
      { from: 'node_modules/../jquery-3.5.1.min.js', to: './dist/js/' },
    ],
  ),
];
```

Then add it as a web accessible resource in your `manifest.json`

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "dist/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
],
```

And then access those within your content/popup scripts.

```
const $ = chrome.runtime.getURL('dist/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js');
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: chrome.extension.getURL(...) is not a function

Comment: Try `chrome.runtime.getURL`

Comment: nothing changed
Uncaught TypeError: chrome.runtime.getURL(...) is not a function

Comment: Here is the documentation for this chrome API: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-getURL. It's not clear why you don't have access to this method in your extension.

Comment: Yes, I saw documentation. I don't know why it is not working. popup,js:

    "use strict";
    import '../css/popup.css';
    import '../icons/iconOn.png';
    import '../icons/iconOff.png';

    const $ = chrome.runtime.getURL('public/js/jquery.min.js');

    $(window).on(
 'click',
 () => { alert('hello from popup.js!') });